# How to export the OWASP ZAP Spider report to Excel?

Tags: security, owasp, zap

I am running OWASP ZAP Spider on a domain and retrieving the list of URLs. In the list I can see few OUT OF SCOPE URLs as shown in the image below.

[image: OWASP ZAP Spider list of links Traversed]

I want to export all this output into an excel (including all the entries tagged as "OUT OF SCOPE"). Can anyone please help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access this information via the ZAP API, which has a (basic) HTML interface.
Point your browser to the host/port your instance of ZAP is listening on and select: "Local API" / "spider" / "fullResults"
Then enter '0' for the scanId and press the 'fullResults' button. You may also need to supply your API key, which is available from the ZAP Options / API screen.
You can also change the format of the results if you want - HTML, JSON and XML are all supported.

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)

Comment: I did not understand. Can you please elaborate more with images. Really Sorry. New to ZAP.

Comment: Could you please help?

Comment: I'll try to explain a bit more clearly.
Open your browser and point it at the address ZAP is listening on, but default this will be http://localhost:8080
On that page click the link which says "Local API".

Comment: Ugh, ran out of time editing my comment :/ I'll try again:

I'll try to explain a bit more clearly.
Open your browser and point it at the address ZAP is listening on, but default this will be http://localhost:8080
On that page click the link which says "Local API".
On the next page click the "spider link".
On the next page click the "fullResults" link.
You should see a form - enter "0" for the scanId. Press the "fullResults" button. It looks like you wont need the API key, so you dont have to worry about that.
Is that clearer?

Comment: Ugh: "but default" -> "by default"

Comment: I tried but it's not working. Can you please elaborate with images. Really new to the ZAP and desperately looking for the solution for this.

Comment: Not sure I can attach images here. You could ask on the ZAP user group: http://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users At the very least it would good to know whats not working for you - which of the above steps I detailed doesnt seem to work?

Answer (score 0):

export the findings in an xml format and make sure you name the file. open the excel spreadsheet go to the data tab. from the external data section, choose the tab "from other source" and select the xml option. from there you will be directed to a dialog box where you can browse for the exported xml document. follow the prompts given and it should arrange your data accordingly